# Sending code to the background, waiting, then going back to the main thread without blocking?

Tags: objective-c

A common pattern in Objective C is to run a bit of code in a background thread, then go back to the main thread to make UI adjustments. If the code starts in the main thread, I'd attack this with a pattern like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self someBackgroundTask];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self someUITask];
    });
});
```

However, this seems like a really clunky way to do it, not in the least because it creates two levels of nesting that feeling unnecessary. Is there a better way to do this? Note that the UI code is considered in this instance to be relying on the background task completing, so it can't just be dropped after the first dispatch.

Comment: You can ask NSThread to run someUITask on the main thread. But that gets messy really fast. Blocks are usually preferable. Also blocks are something like 100 orders of magnitude faster than NSThread.

Comment: that looks a correct way to use _GCD_, nothing looks unnecessary in it. what is the actual problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you need to run code on two different threads. All UI operations must run on the main thread, and your blocking operation needs to run on a background thread. At the absolute minimum this would require two lines of code.

GCD makes this fairly simple as you mentioned; I'm not sure any language would have a better way to handle this core issue. Sure, the block syntax is bad (http://fuckingblocksyntax.com); but the core fundamentals are pretty solid.

If the nesting bothers you, try moving all that UI code to a different method, and calling that method from your second nested block. You could even create a method that accepts a **'backgroundWork'** selector/block and a **'foregroundWork'** selector/block. However - I'd argue that the typical UI work you'd perform in such a case would be very minimal, making the extra nesting a minor inconvenience rather than an actual problem.

As far as asynchronous blocks of code that are inter-dependent, check out PromiseKit or even Sequencer; both are good options for supplementing one of Objective C's primary weakness (sequentially performed multi-threaded operations).

I haven't used it myself, but I understand that Facebook/Parse have also released another solution called BFTask, part of the Bolts framework: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS

(Or just use C#)

Comment: Well, conceptually, it's a synchronous dispatch: those codes needs to run on a different thread before the method continues on this thread. That, technically, should be one line, not two. The problem is that when you dispatch_sync from the main thread, the entire main thread just stops and waits, which fundamentally makes sense, but I was looking for a way to do it with similar syntax that wasn't so ugly.

Comment: If PromiseKit and Sequencer don't work for you, checkout Bolts/BFTask (just added a link to my original comment).

Answer (score 0):

Just move all the threading stuff into someBackgroundTask:

```
[self someBackgroundTaskWithCompletion:^{
    [self someUITask];
}];
```

Then do your `dispatch_async()` stuff inside the background task method.